# Complete Old Figure of Friedmann Universe Models

Tags: cosmology, universe, big-bang

I have found this quite old figure (R. D'Inverno, Introducing Einstein's Relativity. Clarendon Press, 1992) that I want to modernize for a course using TikZ/LaTeX.

[image]

My questions are:

- Do you know if the other models visible have a kind of "official name" too?
- What should be added/changed/removed to adapt it to our actual knowledge?

Thanks for your feedback

Comment: Our knowledge of the solution space has not changed. Probably the main change from 1992 is that in the era of precision cosmology, the solutions that clearly do not describe our universe are a lot less interesting. I've never heard of $\Lambda_\mathrm{c}$ or thought about the impact of a negative cosmological constant. Even the study of non-flat cosmologies is niche.

Comment: The graphs that have extrema are often referred to as "cyclic" cosmologies because in such models, the universe expands reaches a maximum then contracts and the begins again. The reason some of them are named is because those models are of significant historical import in the historical study of cosmology. The one labeled "Lemaitre" for the positive curvature $k=+1$, case is the one that was touted as valid when I was in school.